# Android Retrofit onFailure Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, arrays, object, retrofit

I get this error message when I try to get data from my api using Retrofit:

> W/MainActivity: onFailure client: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at path $

I read through a couple of threads, which mostly said to make a  which I made, but it still does not work.

This is the metod to get the data

```
public void getClient() {
    callClient = service.client();
    callClient.enqueue(new Callback<List<ClientResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Response<List<ClientResponse>> response) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onResponse getClient: " + response );
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getClient getData successful: " + response.body().get(0));
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "getClient not successful");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onFailure client: " + t.getMessage() );
        }
    });
}
```

My ApiService Interface

```
public interface ApiService {
    ...
    @GET("client")
    Call<List<ClientResponse>> client();
    ...
}

My Client Model
public class Client {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String created_at;
    public String updated_at;

    public Client(int id, String name, String email, String created_at, String updated_at) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }
    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
    public String getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }
    public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }
}
```

My ClientResponse

```
public class ClientResponse {
    List<Client> data;
    public List<Client> getData() { return data; }
    public void setData(List<Client> data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

This is how my current json output looks like, I copied it from postman:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mad Max",
        "email": "mad@max.com",
        "created_at": "2017-07-26 09:57:22",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-26 09:57:22"
    }
}
```

Comment: It means you are getting response as an object not an arry

Comment: can u post your json response

Comment: post response JSON format

Comment: @Anil I updated the question with the json response / format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that coming response is `object` but your current response is `Array`

your response `List<ClientResponse>` and I think it should be `ClientResponse` object

```
public class ClientResponse {
    public Client data;
    public Client getData() { return data; }
    public void setData(Client data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

To get the data

```
public void getClient() {
    callClient = service.client();
    callClient.enqueue(new Callback<List<ClientResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Response<List<ClientResponse>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                // first way to get data
                Client client =response.body().data;
                // second way but i dont prefer it .but you want it as per ou r 
                //discussion 
                response.body().setData(response.body().data);
                Client client =response.body().getData();

                // third way to get data
                ClientResponse clientResponse = response.body();
                Log.w(TAG, "getClient getData successful: " +
                    clientResponse.getData().getName());
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "getClient not successful");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ClientResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onFailure client: " + t.getMessage() );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi ok I do not get an error (I get a 200 which is fine), but I also do not get any data `response.isSuccessful` returns me this `getClient getData successful: com.fooj.myapp.entities.Client@c5dadf5`, how can I show / return data?

Comment: just use response.body().data and you should use the ClientResponse  i mentioned in the answer

Comment: does not work I am using this `response.body().getData()` the getData() method is from my Client response `public Client getData() { return data; }`

Comment: ok you should pass the data before retrieve  it .So pass the data first response.body().setData(response.body().data)

Comment: Could you edit your answer and show me how it would look like then please

Comment: @utdev please check the answer

Comment: ok Mina I made it work like this: `ClientResponse clientResponse = response.body();Log.w(TAG, "getClient getData successful: " + clientResponse.getData().getName());` could you put that in your answer :)

Comment: @utdev i did. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may should modify your ApiService interface to

```
@GET("client")
Call<ClientResponse> client();
```

and `ClientResponse` should be

```
  public class ClientResponse {
     public Client data;
     public Client getData() { return data; }
        public void setData(Client data) { this.data = data; }
  }
```